# Inhomogeneous Hidden Markov Model

Tags: hidden-markov-model, transition-matrix

I've recently been working on Inhomogeneous Hidden Markov Model (IHMM) as defined in [this article](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/225892). In short, the whole idea distinguishing IHMM from typical HMM is that a transition matrix $A = \{a_{ij}\}$ is now time-variant, so $A(\tau) = \{a_{ij}(\tau)\}$.

[image]

Such change entails a reformulation of the forward variable, that now looks like this
\begin{align}
    \alpha_t(i, d) = \mathbb{P}(O_1, ..., O_t, q_t = i, d_t(i) = d \mid \lambda)
\end{align}
Initialization
\begin{align}
\alpha_1(i,1) &= \pi_t b_i(O_1)\\
\alpha_1(i,d) &= 0 \ \text{for} \ d > 1
\end{align}
Recursion
\begin{align}
\alpha_{t+1}(j,1) &= \sum\limits_{\tau=1}^t \sum\limits_{i=1}^N \alpha_t(i, \tau)a_{ij}(\tau)b_j(O_{t+1})\\
\alpha_{t+1}(j,d+1) &= \alpha_t(j,d)a_{jj}(d)b_j(O_{t+1})
\end{align}
for $d = 1,2, ...,t, \ j = 1, 2,...,N, \ t = 1,2,...,T-1$.

The thing that I have hard time understanding is why $\alpha_{t+1}(j,1)$ looks as it looks, especially why there's a summation over $\tau$ but only up to $t$. So, let's say I need $\alpha_{4+1}(j,1)$, why should I limit myself to only $t = 4$ in the outer sum? Cannot this state last longer? I find it really non-intuitive.